# How to insert HTML in TabPanel tab text?

Tags: gwt

When adding a tab in a TabPanel in GWT the parameter is:

```
public void add(Widget w, String tabText){...};
```

How to tell the TabPanel to treat 'tabtext' as HTML? Because the string I am inserting is actually a HTML. Inserting HTML in MenuItem can be easily be done with MenuItem:

```
public MenuItem(String text, boolean asHTML, Command cmd){...}
```

However, this is not the case with TabPanel, anyone have ideas to insert HTML with TabPanel 'tabText'?

Thanks

Comment: You get some right answers, please mark them as accepted. Otherwise your future questions will go unnoticed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is this method according to the JavaDoc for TabPanel: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabPanel.html

[image]

I haven't actually tried if it works or not, but it should!

Good luck!